# Excel Pivot Table Import limitations

Tags: database, excel, import, connection, pivot

Does anyone happen to know if there is a limit on the amount of rows you can include in an import into a Pivot table from SQL?  I'm importing about 115 million rows into the pivot table because I know there is a limit on the amount of rows excel can house in a single worksheet but does this same limitation apply to importing from data connections?

Answer (score 1):

The limits are set by your computer's memory: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211517